# How can I retrieve Latitude and Longitude of a postal address using Bing Maps?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, bing-maps, geo

I want to be able to retrieve the geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude) for a given address. I'm hoping I can do that if I have the full address (street address + city + state + zip).

If it matters, I am using Bing Maps. The skeleton code I've got is this (fullAddress, AddPushpin(), and getGeoCordsForAddress() are the most pertinent parts):

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fullAddress = string.Empty;
    if (MissingValues()) return;    

    mapName = cmbxMapName.SelectedItem.ToString();
    locationName = txtbxLocation.Text;
    address = txtbxAddress.Text;
    city = txtbxCity.Text;
    st8 = txtbxSt8.Text;
    zip = txtbxZip.Text;
    mapDetailNotes = richtxtbxMapNotes.Text;
    fullAddress = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", address, city, st8, zip);

    if (InsertIntoCartographerDetail())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("insert succeeded"); 
        AddPushpin(fullAddress);
        ClearControls();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("insert failed");
    }        
}

private void AddPushpin(string fullAddress)
{
    GeoCoordinate geoCoord = getGeoCordsForAddress(fullAddress);
    Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
    pin.Location = new Location(geoCoord.Latitude, geoCoord.Longitude);
    . . .
}

private GeoCoordinate getGeoCordsForAddress(string fullAddress)
{
   GeoCoordinate gc = new GeoCoordinate();
   . . . // What goes here?
   return gc;
}
```

Comment: Found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/find-a-location-by-address

Comment: You can take a look at this library: [Generic C# Geocoding API](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net) that allows to get address information including coordinates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Latitude Longitude from an address c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943787/get-latitude-longitude-from-an-address-c-sharp)

Comment: [Generic C# Geocoding API - GitHub](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net) -- [Bing Maps V8 Code Samples](https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Welcome)

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has an official [BingMapsRESTToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which helps you to work with [Bing Maps REST Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/bingmaps/rest-services/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) easily. To do so, you need to install [BingMapsRESTToolkit NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BingMapsRESTToolkit?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Here, you are interested in [GeocodeRequest](https://github.com/microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/blob/master/Docs/API%20Reference.md?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#-geocoderequest-class) to get location by address.

**Example - Get latitude and longitude by address and create a pushpin on map**

Install [BingMapsRESTToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BingMapsRESTToolkit?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) NuGet Package and run the following code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var request = new GeocodeRequest();
   request.BingMapsKey = "YOUR MAP KEY";

   request.Query = "172 Jalan Pinang, 50088 Kuala Lumpur, " +
           "Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia";
   //OR
   //request.Address = new SimpleAddress()
   //{
   //    CountryRegion = "Malaysia",
   //    AddressLine = "172 Jalan Pinang",
   //    AdminDistrict = "Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur",
   //    PostalCode = "50088",
   //};

   var result = await request.Execute();
   if (result.StatusCode == 200)
   {
       var toolkitLocation = (result?.ResourceSets?.FirstOrDefault())
               ?.Resources?.FirstOrDefault()
               as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location;
       var latitude = toolkitLocation.Point.Coordinates[0];
       var longitude = toolkitLocation.Point.Coordinates[1];
       var mapLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(latitude, longitude);
       this.userControl11.myMap.SetView(mapLocation, 15);
       var p = new Pushpin() { Location = mapLocation, ToolTip = "KLCC Park" };
       this.userControl11.myMap.Children.Add(p);
   }
}
```

[image]

**How to use WPF Bing Maps in Windows Forms:**

- [How can I add a Bing Maps Component to my C# Winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464892/3110834)
- [Getting Bing Maps key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/getting-started/bing-maps-dev-center-help/getting-a-bing-maps-key?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

**Bing Maps REST Toolkit related resources:**

- [Getting Started](https://github.com/microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/blob/master/Docs/Getting%20Started.md?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [API Reference](https://github.com/microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/blob/master/Docs/API%20Reference.md?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Project Homepage](https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BingMapsRESTToolkit?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)