# Why does only a subset of my Pins display on the Bing Map in one particular scenario?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, async-await, bing-maps

In my app, the user can either load a text file (semi-colon delimited) which describes the characteristics of locations to be turned into [Push]Pins on a Bing Map, or load pre-existing map data (from a local database) to the same end.

In the case of loading from the database, it's working great and a Pin is displayed on the map for every corresponding record in the database, such as this:

[image]

But when I populate the database from the contents of the text file and then create Pins based on those values, only a subset of the pins display on the map - usually just the first two, in fact!

But then, when I load the same map from the database, all displays as it should.

I've checked the database after generating the new records from the text file, and all the records are indeed there (including the coordinates (Latitude and Longitude values). The code seems to be the same in both cases. But it's not displaying all the Pins...

The text file contents are such as this (this is what created the map shown above):

```
Paris, France;;Paris;France;75000
Florence, Italy;;Florence;Italy;50100
Chelsea, London, England;23 Tedworth Square;Chelsea London;England;SW3 4DY
Kaltenleutgeben, Austria;;Kaltenleutgeben;Austria;2380
Vienna, Austria;;Vienna;Austria;1010
Weggis, Switzerland;;Weggis;Switzerland;6006
Heidelberg, Germany;;Heidelberg;Germany;69115
Munich, Germany;;Munich;Germany;80331
```

To get down to the nitty-gritty, here is the code in the main form that loads the map data from a text file, such as the one shown immediately above:

```
private void toolStripMenuItemCreateMapAndLocsFromFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool pushpinsAdded = false;
    string _currentMap = string.Empty;
    RemoveCurrentPushpins();

    using (var frmCre8MapAndLocsFromFile = new mdlDlgCreateMapAndLocsFromTSVFile())
    {
        if (frmCre8MapAndLocsFromFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _currentMap = mdlDlgCreateMapAndLocsFromTSVFile.CurrentMap;
            foreach (Pushpin pin in frmCre8MapAndLocsFromFile.Pins)
            {
                this.userControl11.myMap.Children.Add(pin);
                pushpinsAdded = true; // redundant after the first assignment
            }
        }
    }
    if (pushpinsAdded)
    {
        RightsizeZoomLevelForAllPushpins();
    }
    lblMapName.Text = currentMap;
    lblMapName.Visible = true;
}
```

Here's the pertinent code from mdlDlgCreateMapAndLocsFromTSVFile (yes, it's misnamed, because I switched from TSV to SCSV), which is invoked above:

```
private void btnOpenTSVFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pathToFile = string.Empty;
    string line = string.Empty;
    int counter = 0;
    openTSVFileDlg.Filter = "scsv files (*.scsv)|*.scsv|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    
    if (openTSVFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pathToFile = openTSVFileDlg.FileName;
        fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(pathToFile); 
        fileNameOnly = Path.ChangeExtension(fileNameOnly, null);
        CurrentMap = fileNameOnly;
        if (SCSVFileAlreadyLoaded(fileNameOnly))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The file/table {0} has already been loaded/populated", fileNameOnly));
            return;
        }
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(pathToFile);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                InsertMapRecord(fileNameOnly);
            }
            counter++;
            InsertMapDetailRecord(fileNameOnly, line);
        }
    }
}
```

InsertMapDetailRecord() is the method that adds the pushpins to the List, and it is:

```
private void InsertMapDetailRecord(string fileNameOnly, string line)
{
    string keyRecordElements = string.Empty;
    string[] lineElements;
    lineElements = line.Split(';');
    string locationName = lineElements[0].Trim();
    string address = lineElements[1].Trim();
    string city = lineElements[2].Trim();
    string st8 = lineElements[3].Trim();
    string zip = lineElements[4].Trim();
    keyRecordElements = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", address, city, st8, zip).Trim();
    if (MissingValues(lineElements))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not insert record - one or more key values missing");
        return;
    }

    if (InsertIntoCartographerDetail(fileNameOnly, locationName, address, city, st8, zip))
    {
        AddPushpin(keyRecordElements, locationName);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("insert failed");
    }
}
```

AddPushpin() is:

```
private async void AddPushpin(string _fullAddress, string _location)
{
    iContentCounter = iContentCounter + 1;
    // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752688/how-can-i-retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-postal-address-using-bing-maps
    var request = new GeocodeRequest();
    request.BingMapsKey = "Gr8GooglyMoogly";
    request.Query = _fullAddress;

    var result = await request.Execute();
    if (result.StatusCode == 200)
    {
        var toolkitLocation = (result?.ResourceSets?.FirstOrDefault())
                ?.Resources?.FirstOrDefault()
                as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location;
        var latitude = toolkitLocation.Point.Coordinates[0];
        var longitude = toolkitLocation.Point.Coordinates[1];
        var mapLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(latitude, longitude);
        this.Pin = new Pushpin() { Location = mapLocation, ToolTip = _location, Content = iContentCounter 
     };
        if (null == this.Pins)
        {
            this.Pins = new List<Pushpin>();
        }
        this.Pins.Add(Pin); // specific to this form
        UpdateDetailRecWithCoords(_location, latitude, longitude); 
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Again, this does what it's supposed to do as far as populating the database, including the Detail table's Latitude and Longitude fields, but only two pushpins display on the map after focus is passed back to the main form when the modal dialog is closed.

Here is the code from the main form that invokes mdlDlgFrm_LoadExistingMap:

```
private void loadExistingMapToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool pushpinsAdded = false;
    RemoveCurrentPushpins();
    using (var frmLoadExistingMap = new mdlDlgFrm_LoadExistingMap())
    {
        if (frmLoadExistingMap.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (Pushpin pin in frmLoadExistingMap.Pins) 
            {
                this.userControl11.myMap.Children.Add(pin);
                pushpinsAdded = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (pushpinsAdded)
    {
        RightsizeZoomLevelForAllPushpins();
    }
    lblMapName.Text = currentMap;
    lblMapName.Visible = true;
}
```

And here is the code from the mdlDlgFrm_LoadExistingMap form, which :

```
private void btnLoadSelectedMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string latitudeAsStr = string.Empty;
    string longitudeAsStr = string.Empty;
    List<MapDetails> lstMapDetails = new List<MapDetails>();
    MapDetails md;
    const int LOC_NAME = 0;
    const int ADDRESS = 1;
    const int CITY = 2;
    const int ST8 = 3;
    const int ZIP = 4;
    const int NOTES = 5;
    const int LATITUDE = 6;
    const int LONGITUDE = 7;
 
    mapName = cmbxMaps.Text.Trim();
    if (mapName == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a map from the combo box");
        cmbxMaps.Focus();
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        Form1.currentMap = mapName; 
        string qry = "SELECT LocationName, Address1, City, StateOrSo, PostalCode, " +
                                "MapDetailNotes, Latitude, Longitude " +
                                "FROM CartographerDetail " +
                                "WHERE FKMapName = @FKMapName";
        var con = new SqliteConnection(connStr);
        con.Open();
        SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(qry, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FKMapName", mapName);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            md = new MapDetails();
            md.LocationName = reader.GetValue(LOC_NAME).ToString().Trim();
            md.Address = reader.GetValue(ADDRESS).ToString().Trim();
            md.City = reader.GetValue(CITY).ToString().Trim();
            md.StateOrSo = reader.GetValue(ST8).ToString().Trim();
            md.PostalCode = reader.GetValue(ZIP).ToString().Trim();
            md.MapDetailNotes = reader.GetValue(NOTES).ToString();
            latitudeAsStr = reader.GetValue(LATITUDE).ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(latitudeAsStr))
            {
                md.Latitude = 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                md.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(LATITUDE).ToString());
            }
            longitudeAsStr = reader.GetValue(LONGITUDE).ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(longitudeAsStr))
            {
                md.Longitude = 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                md.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(LONGITUDE).ToString());
            }
            lstMapDetails.Add(md);
        }
        AddPushpinsToListOfPushpins(lstMapDetails);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    this.Close();
}

// AddPushpins (plural)
private void AddPushpinsToListOfPushpins(List<MapDetails> lstMapDetails)
{
    string fullAddress;

    foreach (MapDetails _md in lstMapDetails)
    {
        fullAddress = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", _md.Address, _md.City, _md.StateOrSo, _md.PostalCode).Trim();
        AddPushpinToListOfPushpins(_md.LocationName, fullAddress, _md.MapDetailNotes, _md.Latitude,                 _md.Longitude);
    }
}

// AddPushpin (singular)
private async void AddPushpinToListOfPushpins(string location, string fullAddress, string mapDetailNotes, double latitude, double longitude)
{
    iContentCounter = iContentCounter + 1;
    string toolTip = string.Empty;
    // if already have the record, including the coordinates, no need to make the REST call
    if ((latitude != 0.0) && (longitude != 0.0))
    {
        if (mapDetailNotesExist(location))
        {
            toolTip = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3},{4}{1}{5}", location, Environment.NewLine, fullAddress, latitude,                 longitude, mapDetailNotes.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            toolTip = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3},{4}", location, Environment.NewLine, fullAddress, latitude,                         longitude);
        }
        var _mapLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(latitude, longitude);
        this.Pins.Add(new Pushpin()
        {
            Location = _mapLocation,
            ToolTip = toolTip,
            Content = iContentCounter
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752688/how-can-i-retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-postal-                address-using-bing-maps
        var request = new GeocodeRequest();
        request.BingMapsKey = "Gr8GooglyMoogly";
        request.Query = fullAddress;

        var result = await request.Execute();
        if (result.StatusCode == 200)
        {
            var toolkitLocation = (result?.ResourceSets?.FirstOrDefault())
                    ?.Resources?.FirstOrDefault()
                    as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location;
            var _latitude = toolkitLocation.Point.Coordinates[0];
            var _longitude = toolkitLocation.Point.Coordinates[1];
            var mapLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(_latitude, _longitude);
            this.Pins.Add(new Pushpin() 
            { 
                Location = mapLocation,
                ToolTip = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3},{4}{1}{5}", location, Environment.NewLine, fullAddress, _latitude,                         _longitude, mapDetailNotes),
                Content = iContentCounter 
            });
            UpdateLocationWithCoordinates(location, _latitude, _longitude);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me the code to create the Pins and then display them in the map is the same whether I create a map from a file or if I load a map from the database. So why is the behavior different?

### UPDATE

To give an even more concrete example, when creating a map via file with contents like this (excerpt of first few rows):

```
July 15 & 16, 1895 - Music Hall, Cleveland, Ohio;; Cleveland;Ohio;44101
July 18, 1895 - Soo Opera House or Hotel Iroquois, Sault Ste. Marie, Michigan;;Sault Ste. Marie;Michigan;49783
July 19, 1895 - Casino Room, Grand Hotel, Mackinac, Michigan;;Mackinac;Michigan;49757
July 20, 1895 - Grand Opera House, Petoskey, Michigan;;Petoskey;Michigan;49770
July 22, 1895 - First Methodist Church, Duluth, Minnesota;;Duluth;Minnesota;55802
July 23, 1895 - Hotel West & Reception and Supper, Minneapolis, Minnesota;;Minneapolis;Minnesota;55111
July 24, 1895 - People's Church, St. Paul, Minnesota;;St. Paul;Minnesota;55101
July 27, 1895 - Luncheon and Manitoba Club Supper, Winnipeg, Canada;;Winnipeg;Canada;R0G 0A1
```

...I get this at first (only a subset, and all of them with the same content number):

[image]

...but when I immediately thereafter load the map via "Load Existing" I get it all:

[image]

?

### UPDATE 2

Thanks to "The Bing Maps Whisperer," Reza Aghaei, it is now working:

[image]

Comment: A bit hard to tell as there is a lot going on here. The one thing that stands out to me is the AddPushpin and AddPushpinToListOfPushpins methods are both "async void" which can sometimes hide errors. Try wrapping the code in those methods with try/catch and add a breakpoint in the catch to verify if those methods are executing correctly, or throwing and hiding an error.

Comment: **1-** Change `AddPushpin` signature to `async Task AddPushpin(...)` **2-** Then in `InsertMapDetailRecord` change the call to `await AddPushpin(...);` **3-** Change `InsertMapDetailRecord` signature to `async Task InsertMapDetailRecord(...)` **4-** Change `btnOpenTSVFile_Click` signature to `async void btnOpenTSVFile_Click` **5-** Then in `btnOpenTSVFile_Click` change the call `InsertMapDetailRecord` to `await InsertMapDetailRecord()`

Comment: I also guess you should: **6-** In `AddPushpin` method, remove `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` **7-** In `btnOpenTSVFile_Click`, add `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` right after end of while loop.

Comment: Basically when in method `void M(...)` you want to call a method `DoSomething(...)` which returns `Task`, change the call to `await DoSomething(...);`. Then if method `M` is an event handler, change the signature to `async void M(...)`, otherwise if its a normal method, change the signature to `async Task M(...)`.

Comment: The reason that I think you need to change the signatures and also the line that you set dialog result: In `AddPushpin`, you are setting `DialogResult` to `OK`, which means after adding the first pushpin, the containing dialog (`mdlDlgCreateMapAndLocsFromTSVFile`) will be closed and you start looking into `Pins` property (which still behind the scene is getting filled, then after adding the first few pushpins which had chance to be added to Pins property, you dispose the `mdlDlgCreateMapAndLocsFromTSVFile` and no more pushpin will be added to the map.

Comment: Gr8, thanks Reza ("Bing Maps Whisperer"); make this an answer, and I will give you the Bounty. It works perfectly, except the numbering is off (pushpins show 2,4, and 6 when loaded from the file, but when I then load them "from existing" they appear as 1,2, and 3 as expected). I'm sure I can figure that part out. So Cre8 from File is now working, as I show in Update 2. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! I'll do -  Just one point about the variables/fields, I see you are using fields (for example  `iContentCounter`) like variables by changing them inside the methods; You know your requirements better  but it's usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the fixes that I see you need to apply:

1. Change `AddPushpin` signature to `async Task AddPushpin(...)`
2. Then in `InsertMapDetailRecord` change the call to `await AddPushpin(...);`
3. Change `InsertMapDetailRecord` signature to `async Task InsertMapDetailRecord(...)`
4. Change `btnOpenTSVFile_Click` signature to `async void btnOpenTSVFile_Click`
5. Then in `btnOpenTSVFile_Click` change the call `InsertMapDetailRecord` to `await InsertMapDetailRecord()`

I also guess you should:

6. In `AddPushpin` method, remove `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`
7. In `btnOpenTSVFile_Click`, add `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` right after end of while loop.

**Using async/await**

Basically when in method `void M(...)` you want to call a method `DoSomething(...)` which returns `Task`, change the call to `await DoSomething(...);`. Then if method `M` is an event handler, change the signature to `async void M(...)`, otherwise if its a normal method, change the signature to `async Task M(...)`.

**Setting DialogResult**

The reason that I think you need to change the signatures and also the line that you set dialog result: In `AddPushpin`, you are setting `DialogResult` to OK, which means after adding the first pushpin, the containing dialog (`mdlDlgCreateMapAndLocsFromTSVFile`) will be closed and you start looking into Pins property (which still behind the scene is getting filled, then after adding the first few pushpins which had chance to be added to Pins property, you dispose the `mdlDlgCreateMapAndLocsFromTSVFile` and no more pushpin will be added to the map.

**Scope of variables**

We don't see the whole code, but pay attention to the scope of the variables/fields. Just as a warning, It's not a very good idea to access class fields throughout your methods, they are not local variables and when you change those values, the change is visible to other methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

Possible and Probable issue:
Multithreading and assignment to Instance level reference.

TLDR; in AddPushpin() , use local variable instead of instance variable.
replace `this.Pin = new Pushpin()` with `var pin=new Pushpin()` and then add this local variable to collection (You might want to change this collection with threadsafe one)

Explanation:

```
While Loop -> InsertMapDetailRecord() ->  AddPushpin(){
    1. thread is paused
    2. New object is assigned to instance variable
    3. Instance variable is added to collection

}
```

It is likely due to an instance variable objects are overridden by another instance before it could be added to the collection. Thus only a few objects are available in the collection. (As you have mentioned subset is loaded but this count is not consistent and varies for each run ?)